# Doctrine2 split Query Builder

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm using QueryBuilder to execute a complex query with Doctrine2.

I'd like to split this query in order to define or not some conditions.

It would then look like that:

```
$logs = $em->getRepository("Shs\Entity\Log")
           ->createQueryBuilder("log")
           ->where("log.client = :client")
           ->setParameter("client", $client);

if($search != ""){
    $logs->andWhere("log.name LIKE :search")
         ->setParameter("search", "%" . $search . "%");
}

$logs->addOrderBy("log.date", "DESC")
     ->getQuery()->execute();
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

If I write that in a single block it works:

```
$logs = $em->getRepository("Shs\Entity\Log")
           ->createQueryBuilder("log")
           ->where("log.client = :client")
           ->andWhere("log.name LIKE :search")
           ->setParameter("search", "%" . $search . "%")
           ->setParameter("client", $client)
           ->addOrderBy("log.date", "DESC")
           ->getQuery()->execute();;
```

If I redefine $logs each time it works but I don't get why:

```
$logs = $em->getRepository("Shs\Entity\Log")
           [...]
           ->setParameter("client", $client);

if($search != ""){
    $logs = $logs->andWhere("log.name LIKE :search")
         ->setParameter("search", "%" . $search . "%");
}

$logs = $logs->addOrderBy("log.date", "DESC")
     ->getQuery()->execute();
```

In the QueryBuilder class I saw that the add function has a parameter $append=false.
The addOrderBy function (for instance) calls the add function but sets $append to true :

```
public function addOrderBy($sort, $order = null)
{
    return $this->add('orderBy', $sort . ' ' . (! $order ? 'ASC' : $order), true);
}
```

If I force $append to false it works too but I won't touch this class.

What would be the best way to achieve what I want to do? Should I use $qb->add() instead of $qb->where() etc. or is there a way to do this with $qb->where()?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I redefine $logs each time it works but I don't get why:**

I'm guessing that you may have an error elsewhere that got lost when you copied/pasted your query.  Consider distinguishing between a collection of logs and the query builder.  Something like:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository("Shs\Entity\Log")
       ->createQueryBuilder("log")
       ->where("log.client = :client")
       ->setParameter("client", $client);

if($search != ""){
    $qb->andWhere("log.name LIKE :search")->setParameter("search", "%" . $search . "%");
}

$qb->addOrderBy("log.date", "DESC");

$logs = $qb->getQuery()->getResults();
```

Using the execute() method is also a bit strange.  Normally you would use some variation of getResults() for queries.

Comment: It works and I got it, thanks! :) It's possible to split it which is logical because it returns itself each time but I guess I didn't get the results back because I confused the qb and the results... So $logs = $qb->getQuery()->execute() solves this issue and there's obviously no need to redefine $logs several times. I'll get informed about getResult(), too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

I think you should achieve that by this code:

```
$logs = $em->createQueryBuilder()
           ->select("log")
            ->from("Shs\Entity\Log log")
           ->where("log.client = :client")
           ->setParameter("client", $client);

if($search != ""){
    $logs->andWhere("log.name LIKE :search")
         ->setParameter("search", "%" . $search . "%");
}

$logs->addOrderBy("log.date", "DESC")
     ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: ->from("Shs\Entity\Log", "log"). Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem... Again, if I write $logs = $logs->... it works though.

Comment: Yes, this should work too (both are possible I think). To be honest, I don't understand the question. Maybe try to redefine or be more specific.

Comment: If I echo $logs->getQuery()->getSQL(): Your code displays "SELECT log FROM Shs\Entity\Log log WHERE log.client = :client AND log.name LIKE :search ORDER BY log.date DESC". When I write it in a single block it shows "SELECT l0_.id AS id0, l0_.name AS name1, l0_.date AS date2 FROM logs l0_ WHERE l0_.client_id = ? AND l0_.name LIKE ? ORDER BY l0_.date DESC"

Comment: When you create a query builder from a repository (as opposed to directly from the entity manager) then there is no need to use a select or a from clause.  The repository takes care of that for you.